# How to delete a file in QNX4 format when a CF card is mounted as read-only in Linux?

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount, readonly, qnx

Recently, the [DMA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_mechanical_analysis) device of our lab is broken and the suspected problem is in the CF card which is in QNX4 format. I want to delete a file named 'calforce.dat' and recreate it by calibrating the device.

I mount the CF card in my device and got this result:

```
famer@iphyer:~$ sudo mount -t qnx4 /dev/sdb1 /mnt/
[sudo] password for famer: 
mount: warning: /mnt/ seems to be mounted read-only.
famer@iphyer:~$ cd /mnt
famer@iphyer:/mnt$ ls
bin           calfreq.dat  dma           dmasav.dat  fit2.dat      qgui
caldyn.dat    calraw.dat   dma21cfr.dat  dmausr.dat  lib           sbin
calfgen.dat   calres.dat   dmaclamp.dat  etc         license.dat   test_enu.str
calfgres.dat  calrpt.txt   dmaid.dat     exit_case   loader        usr
calforce.dat  devi-ads     dmamfg.dat    fit1.dat    loader_image
```

I want to delete the 'calforce.dat' file but all commands like writing and deleting have been denied by the read-only system.

Commands like:

```
famer@iphyer:/mnt$ sudo mount -o remount,rw /dev/sdb1
[sudo] password for famer: 
mount: warning: /mnt seems to be mounted read-only.
```

do not give any results.

How can I solve it?

Or, alternatively, can I can copy the files out of the CF card to new CF card. Do I need to format a new card before I can use it?
Can I simply use something like GPart or fdisk to realize it?

==========================================================================
Below is what I followed Gilles' suggestion below is what the kernel log since I insert the CF card.

```
Dec 15 12:51:13 MG kernel: [ 1477.242018] usb 1-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
Dec 15 12:51:13 MG kernel: [ 1477.349093] usb 1-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=0158
Dec 15 12:51:13 MG kernel: [ 1477.349099] usb 1-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Dec 15 12:51:13 MG kernel: [ 1477.349102] usb 1-1.1: Product: USB2.0-CRW
Dec 15 12:51:13 MG kernel: [ 1477.349105] usb 1-1.1: Manufacturer: Generic
Dec 15 12:51:13 MG kernel: [ 1477.349107] usb 1-1.1: SerialNumber: 20060413092100000
Dec 15 12:51:14 MG kernel: [ 1477.787682] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
Dec 15 12:51:14 MG kernel: [ 1477.816933] ums-realtek 1-1.1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
Dec 15 12:51:14 MG kernel: [ 1477.818979] scsi6 : usb-storage 1-1.1:1.0
Dec 15 12:51:14 MG kernel: [ 1477.819043] usbcore: registered new interface driver ums-realtek
Dec 15 12:51:15 MG kernel: [ 1478.830020] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Generic- Multi-Card       1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
Dec 15 12:51:15 MG kernel: [ 1478.831859] sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
Dec 15 12:51:16 MG kernel: [ 1479.669070] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] 264096 512-byte logical blocks: (135 MB/128 MiB)
Dec 15 12:51:16 MG kernel: [ 1479.670566] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
Dec 15 12:51:16 MG kernel: [ 1479.670572] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 03 00 00 00
Dec 15 12:51:16 MG kernel: [ 1479.672012] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
Dec 15 12:51:16 MG kernel: [ 1479.672016] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
Dec 15 12:51:16 MG kernel: [ 1479.678399] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
Dec 15 12:51:16 MG kernel: [ 1479.678404] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
Dec 15 12:51:16 MG kernel: [ 1479.679767]  sdb: sdb1
Dec 15 12:51:16 MG kernel: [ 1479.683276] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
Dec 15 12:51:16 MG kernel: [ 1479.683290] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
Dec 15 12:51:16 MG kernel: [ 1479.683292] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
Dec 15 12:52:17 MG kernel: [ 1541.078472] QNX4 filesystem 0.2.3 registered.
```

Does it help?

Comment: Delete the question on [so], otherwise this one will be closed as it against the rules here to cross post.

Comment: OK！ deleted the question！

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with QNX4FS, but I _suspect_ that there's an error in the filesystem, so it's getting mounted read-only to protect the data from (further) corruption. Is it possible that the card got corrupted due to power failure in the middle of a write? You can copy the whole filesystem on the CF card to a normal file on your hard drive using `dd`, and you can mount that file using the loop device.

Comment: The most likely explanation is that the card is read-only. Does it have a read-only switch? If so flip it. There may be clues in the kernel logs (`/var/log/kern.log` on most distributions), if you need help figuring them out edit your question to post the whole sequence of logs from the time you inserted the CF card.

Comment: @Gilles I edited the post!

Comment: @PM2Ring Can I detect the problem? Or how can I make sure that the CF card is broken.

Comment: You could try running [badblocks](http://linux.die.net/man/8/badblocks) on the card. Eg, if the card is `/dev/sde` then `badblocks -v /dev/sde`. But I expect that there would be more useful diagnostic tools on an actual QNX system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Linux 3.18, the QNX4 filesystem driver only supports reading. (Source: the [source](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/qnx4/?v=3.18)). Ditto with QNX6.

There's an [alternate driver with partial read-write support](http://qnxfs.narod.ru/), but it's been unmaintained for several years; you'll probably have to run an older kernel or tweak the code to compile it on a recent kernel.

Alternatively, QNX supports reading ext2 filesystems (I'm not sure about ext4), so you could try making a copy of the CF card that's formatted as ext2. This may or may not be supported on your device though.

Alternatively, run QNX in a virtual machine to update the CF card content.

Comment: Using a virtual machine to update the card sounds like the best plan. But it's probably a good idea to back up the card's current contents (either using something like `rsync` or imaging the whole card using `dd`).

Comment: Yes,but to download [QNX SDP 6.6.0 runtime ISO for VMware or virtual machine](http://www.qnx.com/download/feature.html?programid=26217) You must register your QNX Software Development Platform 6.6.x serial number. This seems terrible to realize for I have no time and money to get it.

Comment: @PM2Ring YEAH.To backup the CF card to another CF card using dd is like this post [Copy bootable linux compact flash to SD card](http://superuser.com/questions/327237/copy-bootable-linux-compact-flash-to-sd-card) But I only have one usb CF card reader? Can I store the data on my home directory and then transfer them to a new CF card? Or this method can not realize the system format of QNX4?

Comment: @sikisis: Yes, you can use `dd` to store the card data as a single file to your hard drive, eg `dd if=/dev/sde of=cfimage` will save it to a file named `cfimage` in the current directory. And you can copy that image to a new card using `dd of=/dev/sde if=cfimage`. Virtual machine programs often use such disk image files to create fake devices. For this stuff, it doesn't matter what the filesystem is on the card, `dd` is just tranferring raw blocks of bytes.

Comment: @sikisis: There are options you could give `dd` to speed up the copying operation by specifying a larger block size, but the default settings work ok and are probably safest if you're not familiar with `dd`, especially if the card is corrupt.

Comment: @PM2Ring How about when my new CF card have been formatted FAT16 already?   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *          63      993887      496912+   6  FAT16

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19485/discussion-between-sikisis-and-pm-2ring).